# como pongo Apache tomcat en puerto 80 con authbind si ejecuto apache tomcat en carpeta y no lo tengo instalado?

Tags: linux, netbeans, apache, tomcat

Estoy en una maquina virtual ejecutando Lubuntu y estoy en el puerto 8080 y quiero cambiarme al puerto 80, pero ejecuto el servidor apache tomcat desde el una carpeta que descargue osea que no esta instalado en la sistema. Existe alguna manera de poderme cambiar al puerto 80

Si no me he explicado bien, por favor díganmelo hacer para proporcionar mas contexto

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donde meta sudo quiere decir que hace falta el root

Primero asegurate que tienes el puerto abierto del firewall, lo puedes lograr con el siguiente comando:

```
 sudo ufw 80
```

Después añadimos el puerto en el authbinding y le añadimos permisos (Nota tomcat puede variar su nombre):

```
   sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
   sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
   sudo chown tomcat /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

En caso de que el usuario tomcat no sea root debemos hacer lo siguiente:

**A partir de aquí es necesario estar conectado con el usuario root.**

En el archivo `ruta a tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` (donde ruta a tomcat es la ruta hacia la carpeta tomcat) añadir el siguiente:

```
 CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

Si no existe crear el fichero con el siguiente comando:

```
touch ruta a tomcat/bin/setenv.sh
```

Una vez hecho esto se tiene que cambiar en el archivo siguiente `ruta a tomcat/bin/startup.sh`

```
exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```

Por:

```
exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
```

Reiniciar el tomcat:

```
systemctl restart tomcat
```

Está probado en tomcat 10.1.10 sin instalar y java 11.0.29 en un ubuntu 22.04.2 lts desktop

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentare hacer